# Определение понятия API

Tags: веб-программирование, api, backend

Немного запутался в том, что конкретно является API, а что нет. Как я понял, API - это то, посредством чего общаются 2 серверных приложения. Но при этом API также называют интерфейс для общения бекенда и фронтенда. В интернете увидел определение, что Django REST framework (DRF) - инструмент для создания API. Но разве сам Django не создает API для общения бекенда и фронтенда?

Также в одном видео услышал что-то из разряда "REST API это не про клиентские приложения".
Объясните, пожалуйста, разницу или дайте какие-нибудь ресурсы, где можно про это прочитать.

Comment: Любой интерфейс взаимодействия это по определению API

Answer (score 0):

Из [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/API):

> **API (application programming interface)** — описание способов взаимодействия одной компьютерной программы с другими.

> Если программу (модуль, библиотеку) рассматривать как чёрный ящик, то API — это набор «ручек», которые доступны пользователю данного ящика и которые он может вертеть и переключать.
> Программные компоненты взаимодействуют друг с другом посредством API. При этом обычно компоненты образуют иерархию — высокоуровневые компоненты используют API низкоуровневых компонентов, а те, в свою очередь, используют API ещё более низкоуровневых компонентов.

> A document or standard that describes how to build or use such a connection or interface is called an API specification.

И фронтенд и бэкенд и web-сервер с REST и есть программы, взаимодействующие через некие "точки входа" посредством инструкций, команд и запросов, описанных в спецификациях. Но обычно, Django называют [web-фреймворком](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA), хоть он тоже имеет свои спецификации и описание, как использовать те, или иные его "библиотеки".

Фактически, API нужны для того, чтобы различные программы, как низкоуровневые, так и более высокоуровневые, могли взаимодействовать документированным привычным образом.

Сущуетствует так же [межпроцессное взаимодействие](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/658474) ([Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), или IPC), что несколько отделено стоит по терминологии от понятия API, хотя и на базе IPC может быть выстроено API-взаимодействие: что-то пишет определенную структуру в файл, или сокет и т.д.

Для управления видеокартами тоже может быть свой API: например [WebGPU API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGPU_API).

> WebGL is a JavaScript port of the OpenGL ES 2.0 graphics library, allowing web pages to pass rendering computations directly to the device's GPU to be processed at very high speeds, and render the result inside a  element.

Лично по мне и OpenGL можно так же считать неким API, хотя и следует подождать выводов более профильных спеициалистов. Однако [wiki гласит](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL):

> OpenGL (Open Graphics Library) — спецификация, определяющая платформонезависимый (независимый от языка программирования) программный интерфейс для написания приложений, использующих двумерную и трёхмерную компьютерную графику.
> На базовом уровне OpenGL — это просто спецификация, то есть документ, описывающий набор функций и их точное поведение. Производители оборудования на основе этой спецификации создают реализации — библиотеки функций, соответствующих набору функций спецификации.

**UPDATE:** Как подсказали ниже, в [английской версии wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL):

> OpenGL (Open Graphics Library) -- cross-language, cross-platform application programming interface (API) for rendering 2D and 3D vector graphics.

Вы можете написать сосбтвенную библиотеку, которая принимает определенные структурированные данные, описанные в документации в разделе "library API". Вряд ли кто-то оспорит эту терминологию в вашем пункте README.

Если некая программа за упомянутым REST API управляемая через него, имеет свою спецификацию, то это фактически и есть API. Или, если какой-то запущенный в вашей операционной системе процесс, использует системные вызовы ОС, то эти вызовы -- и есть некий API. Главная задача всевозможных API в OC: чтобы все программмы работали на этой ОС одинаково хорошо и понятных образом. Точно так же и при взаимодейтсвии более высокоуровневых программ -- чтобы эти программы взаимодействовали однаковым и понятным образом.

## TL;DR

Говоря более простым языком, API -- это некий документированный layer для взаимодействия двух программ. Например, посредством более низкоуровневых IPC: тот же REST API работает через протокол http(s), но ваш бэкенд, к примеру, за web-сервер'ом отрабатывает на определенные документированные в спецификации данные в GET/POST запросах, что и есть API.

Если клиентское приложение обращается к REST API, то это отчасти вполне про клиентское приложение, разве что эти запросы обрабатываются на серверной части, а клиент, как вариант, лишь получает и отправляет данные. Просто фраза в вопросе вырвана из контекста -- нужно дальше читать, что подразумевалось.

Comment: Согласно англоязычной википедии: «OpenGL is a cross-language, cross-platform application programming interface (API)»